# How to make a button click get data attribute within its own div?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```html
<?php 
//jQuery calls this code to save changes to inventory
if(isset($_POST['inventoryID'])){
//Filter all incoming fields
$attributeID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['attrID']); 
$inventoryID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['inventoryID']);
$inventorySKU = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9\-]#i', '', $_POST['inventorySKU']); 
$inventorySize = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['inventorySize']);
$inventoryStock = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['inventoryStock']);
$inventoryStatus = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['inventoryStatus']); 

//change letter case
$inventorySKU = strtoupper($inventorySKU); 
$inventorySize = ucwords(strtolower($inventorySize));

 //Check missing fields
 if(!empty($inventorySKU) && !empty($inventorySize) && !empty($inventoryStock) && !empty($inventoryStatus)){  
  //Update row for product into table since there is no changes to image made
  $sql = "UPDATE Inventory SET SKU = '$inventorySKU', Size = '$inventorySize', Stock = '$inventoryStock', Status = '$inventoryStatus' WHERE PK_InventoryID = '$inventoryID' AND FK_AttributesID = '$attributeID'";
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if($query){
   echo 'Your inventory has been successfully updated!';
  }else{
   echo 'FAILURE: Inventory not updated!';
  }
 }
 exit(); 
}
?>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#saveInvSubBtn', function() {
  // Obtain the inventory and attribute ID
  var iID = $('.deleteInvBtn').data("iid");
  var attrID = $('.deleteInvBtn').data("attrid");

  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('inventorySKU', $("#invSKU").val());
  form_data.append('inventorySize', $("#invSize").val());
  form_data.append('inventoryStock', $("#invStock").val());
  form_data.append('inventoryStatus', $("#invStatus").val());

  $.ajax({
    url: 'edit_inventory.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) { // display success(i.e, echo response) response from the PHP script
      if (data === 'Your inventory has been successfully updated!') {
        //do something
      } else {
        //do something else
      }
    },
    error: function() { // display error response(i.e, server timeout etc) from the PHP script
      //display error msg
    }
  });
});
```

I have a div (which consists of text fields and a save button) as shown below. This div is echoed by a PHP script and is dynamic i.e it replicates itself as many times needed according to a PHP WHILE loop via echo function. The div consists of data from a table. If there was 2 rows of data, the div replicates itself twice etc.

What I want to achieve is that when the save button is clicked, the jQuery should obtain the data attribute of the button class "deleteInvBtn" and values of all the text fields WITHIN ITS OWN DIV.

This works only when the first div save button is clicked. When the second div save button is clicked, the jQuery obtains the data attribute and values of text fields from THE FIRST DIV which is not what I need. I understand Jquery click event gets the first ID that is matched from the HTML. How do i solve this please? Please be reminded that both divs shown below or in actual script consists of same classes or IDs.

I tried googling and searching but to no avail. I tried having a data attribute attached to the button itself and still unable to get values of the text fields.

```html
//This is Div 1
    <div class="flex-container-col">
        <form onSubmit="return false;">
        <div>
         <button class="deleteInvBtn" data-iid="5" data-attrid="67" 
         title="Delete Inventory"> 
         <img src="../images/bin.png" width="100%"></button>
                    
         <label for="invSKU">SKU</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSKU" value="BSD-LALA40S">
        </div>
                   
        <div>
         <label for="invSize">SIZE</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSize" value="Small">
        </div>
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStock">STOCK</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border"                      id="invStock" value="11">
          </div>
                    
          <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStatus">STATUS</label>
           <select class="form-text-no-border" id="invStatus">
             //some option statement here
           </select>
         </div>
        </div> 
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <input type="button" class="form-btn" id="saveInvSubBtn" 
             value="SAVE">
        </div>
        </form> 
    </div>


//This is Div 2. Same as above but with diffrent values
    <div class="flex-container-col">
        <form onSubmit="return false;">
        <div>
         <button class="deleteInvBtn" data-iid="8" data-attrid="84" 
         title="Delete Inventory"> 
         <img src="../images/bin.png" width="100%"></button>
                    
         <label for="invSKU">SKU</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSKU" value="KCD-GERA40S">
        </div>
                   
        <div>
         <label for="invSize">SIZE</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSize" value="Medium">
        </div>
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStock">STOCK</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border"                      id="invStock" value="31">
          </div>
                    
          <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStatus">STATUS</label>
           <select class="form-text-no-border" id="invStatus">
             //some option statement here
           </select>
         </div>
        </div> 
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <input type="button" class="form-btn" id="saveInvSubBtn" 
             value="SAVE">
        </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
```

When div 1 save button is clicked, it should obtain div 1 "deleteInvBtn" data attribute and the text fields value within div 1. Likewise when div 2 save button is clicked, it should obtain div 2 "deleteInvBtn" data attribute and the text fields value within div 2.

Comment: You will need to add an **id** based on  an auto-increament interger(number) either gotten from a database or from your loop. Please show us your **PHP** code so we can help you

Comment: I agree with u! The data attributes are actually php driven. I literally just inserted a number here for clarity sake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```js
//try to give the button a specific class instead of .form-btn for this purpose
$('.form-btn').click(function(){
  //from the clicked button find parent with type form then find id of the text field, then get the value.
  alert($(this).parents('form').find('#invSKU').val());
  
  //similarly for other elements.
  alert($(this).parents('form').find('.deleteInvBtn').data('attrid'));
  alert($(this).parents('form').find('.deleteInvBtn').data('iid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//This is Div 1
    <div class="flex-container-col">
        <form onSubmit="return false;">
        <div>
         <button class="deleteInvBtn" data-iid="5" data-attrid="67" 
         title="Delete Inventory"> 
         <img src="../images/bin.png" width="100%"></button>
                    
         <label for="invSKU">SKU</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSKU" value="BSD-LALA40S">
        </div>
                   
        <div>
         <label for="invSize">SIZE</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSize" value="Small">
        </div>
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStock">STOCK</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border"                      id="invStock" value="11">
          </div>
                    
          <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStatus">STATUS</label>
           <select class="form-text-no-border" id="invStatus">
             //some option statement here
           </select>
         </div>
        </div> 
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <input type="button" class="form-btn" id="saveInvSubBtn" 
             value="SAVE">
        </div>
        </form> 
    </div>


//This is Div 2. Same as above but with diffrent values
    <div class="flex-container-col">
        <form onSubmit="return false;">
        <div>
         <button class="deleteInvBtn" data-iid="8" data-attrid="84" 
         title="Delete Inventory"> 
         <img src="../images/bin.png" width="100%"></button>
                    
         <label for="invSKU">SKU</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSKU" value="KCD-GERA40S">
        </div>
                   
        <div>
         <label for="invSize">SIZE</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border" id="invSize" value="Medium">
        </div>
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStock">STOCK</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-text-no-border"                      id="invStock" value="31">
          </div>
                    
          <div class="flex-col-50">
           <label for="invStatus">STATUS</label>
           <select class="form-text-no-border" id="invStatus">
             //some option statement here
           </select>
         </div>
        </div> 
                   
        <div class="flex-container-row">
         <input type="button" class="form-btn" id="saveInvSubBtn" 
             value="SAVE">
        </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
```